# Assistance with a vba project

Tags: vba

I have included vba code for a project I am working on.  The user is prompted for the number of players.  The code used the users answer to set the upper limit of the array.  The problem I am having is that the code lets the user enter the data up to but not including the last entry.

The variable i that I increment by one usually ends up incrementing more.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using a Do..Until loop.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub players()
Dim playername() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim PlayerCount As Long

PlayerCount = InputBox("How many players are there?", "Player Count", "Enter the number of players")

ReDim playername(PlayerCount)

  For i = LBound(playername) To UBound(playername)
   playername(i) = InputBox("Enter player name:", "Player Name", "Player Name")
   MsgBox playername(i) ' test to see if user input is being read
    i = i + 1
  Next i

      Range("A2") = playername(i)  'attempting to add first user name in this cell
      Range("A2").Offset(0, 1).Select ' offset cell for other entries
      ActiveCell = playername(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the (slightly modified) code:

```
For i = LBound(playername) To UBound(playername)
    i = i + 1
Next I
```

The `for` loop *already* runs `i` from the start value to the end value, you generally do *not* want to manually do the same thing within the loop. Doing so will end up skipping values.

In other words, your loop would be more correctly written as:

```
For i = LBound(playername) To UBound(playername)
    playername(i) = InputBox("Enter player name:", "Player Name", "Player Name")
    MsgBox playername(i) ' test to see if user input is being read
Next
```